# How to avoid loops by Vectorizing below code?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, vectorization, bsxfun

The code below is correct, but I want to vectorize it (and may convert to GPU) to increase the speed.

How can I convert it to vector form?

```
RF = 4;     
inhibatory = 0;    
overlap=3;   
act_funct = 'sig';
gap = RF-overlap;    
Image1 = rand(30,22);  
Image2 = rand(27,19); % size_image2 is equal to 27x19
Image3 = rand(30,22); 
de_act_output = de_activate_Mat(Image1,act_funct); % finding derivative of the matrix. e.g. de_act_output = act_output.*(1-act_output) in case of sigmoid. 
for u=1:size(Image1,1)
    for v=1:size(Image1,2)
        sum_val=0;
        iLowMax=max(ceil((u-(RF+inhibatory))/(gap-inhibatory)),1);
        iHighMax=min(floor((u-1)/(gap-inhibatory))+1, size_image2(1));
        jLowMax=max(ceil((v-(RF+inhibatory))/(gap-inhibatory)),1);
        jHighMax = min(floor((v-1)/(gap-inhibatory))+1, size_image2(2));
        sum_sens = sum(sum(Image2(iLowMax:iHighMax,jLowMax:jHighMax)));
        sum_val = sum_sens(:,:) .* Image3(u,v);
        result(u,v) = de_act_output(u,v) .* sum_val;
    end
end
```

Comment: `up_lay_sensitivites`?

Comment: a matrix of same size Up_layerSize in the network. let me edit it.

Comment: @Divakar , Sir any idea?

Comment: Would be nice if you could shorten it to some minimal runable code.

Comment: ok wait i am trying to remove these ifelse as much as i could.

Comment: @Divakar Can you check it now. I have reduce it further. Just to one image. I hope now will be more easy to understand. If i am not wrong. Unfortunately if i directly convert my code to GPU, than it become more worse, 0.5 vs 18sec ... Can you guide me. Should i ask it another question, or is it ok. Regards

Comment: `receptiveFieldSize`?

Comment: @Divakar   receptiveFieldSize = RF. Sorry again for replying late. You can check now

Comment: Corrected, it is the size of image2

Comment: act_funct = sigmoid     de_activate_Mat is a function to find derivative of an activation function.

Comment: So, you mean `de_activate_Mat` is a function, right? What about `act_funct`, is that a variable? How is it formed?

Comment: Yes, act_funct is a char forexample 'sig' . But i have also written it in another form. You can see the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72843/discussion-between-khan-and-divakar).

Comment: `size_image2 = size(Image2);`?

Comment: Yes it is exactly size(Image2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `parallelogram-like` structure of blocks you are creating inside the nested loops with `iLowMax:iHighMax,jLowMax:jHighMax` which won't lead 
to any easy vectorizable codes. But you can go full-throttle vectorization on that if performance is paramount for your case and seems like `convolution` would be of good use there. Listing here are some tweaks to 
make it faster everything around that step by pre-calculating most other stuffs and this must result in appreciable speedup. Here's the implementation -

```
U = 1:size(Image1,1); %// Create arrays of iteration steps
V = 1:size(Image1,2);

%// Calculate arrays of low-high row and column indices 
iLowMax=max(ceil((U-(RF+inhibatory))/(gap-inhibatory)),1);
iHighMax=min(floor((U-1)/(gap-inhibatory))+1, size_image2(1));

jLowMax=max(ceil((V-(RF+inhibatory))/(gap-inhibatory)),1);
jHighMax = min(floor((V-1)/(gap-inhibatory))+1, size_image2(2));

sens_sums(size(Image1,1),size(Image1,2)) = 0; %// Pre-allocation
for u=1:size(Image1,1)
    for v=1:size(Image1,2)
        sens = Image2(iLowMax(u):iHighMax(u),jLowMax(v):jHighMax(v));
        sens_sums(u,v) = sum(sens(:));
    end
end
result = sens_sums.*Image3.*de_act_output;
```

Comment: yes, it work, and have some little bit of improvement compare to the old. I am leaving for room. will talk on it later. Thanks alot till now.

Comment: yes convolution will be good, but a bit hard, as after a long strugle i was successful to use conv2 for the previous solution that you provided, and it gave me little bit improvement over your vectorized code. Will show details later.

Comment: The difference between the time taken by conv2 and your provided vectorized code in previous question is 0.0653 vs 0.0360 respectively. Now for this problem can you tell me how can i use conv2 for this structure?

Comment: @khan Sorry, I am not sure really, but the pattern of "parallelogram-like structure" made me think that way.

Comment: i am also trying to utilize my GPU, but if i convert the same code to gpu, it becomes worst, I dont know how can i make it better, so that i may also utilize gpu

Comment: @khan Because of the existing loops, I think you are better off with CPU code.